# Инвертировать клавиши управления громкостью

Tags: windows, windows-10, клавиатура

На клавиатуре есть колёсико для управления громкостью. Проблема в том, что если крутить его вниз, то громкость увеличивается, а если вверх, то уменьшается. Хояу сделать наоборот. Скорее всего оно работает как медиакнопки громкости - увеличение и уменьшение. Можно их как-то интертировать?

[image: Фото колёсика]

Comment: Скайпель и паяльник) перекрести контакты щелкаклке

Comment: @eri, а программно?)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью  бесплатной программы с открытым исходным кодом [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) используя конфигурацию, подобную такой:

```
$Volume_Down::Send Volume_Up
$Volume_Up::Send Volume_Down
```

Тут `$` не позволяет далее запускать рекурсивное применение правила.

У меня нет мультимедийных клавиш, поэтому не могу проверить, но вот такая конфигурация корректно меняет буквы местами:

```
$a::Send b
$b::Send a
```

Comment: Хм.. Неужели оно не зациклится?

Comment: Не должно. Дополнил ответ.